# Restricting Sales Representatives to View Only Their Own Orders in PrestaShop 8.1.1

Tags: php, symfony, permissions, controller, prestashop

In PrestaShop 8.1.1, I created a profile named 'Sales Representative'. This profile has an ID of 5. I've added the appropriate permissions so that they can't do anything other than add, edit, and view orders on the admin page. The problem is that I would like each sales representative to only see the orders that they themselves have added in the orders tab..

I've seen a similar problem solved before, but it was on PrestaShop version 1.7 or lower. Now the controllers have changed and there is no typical AdminOrdersController.php. I also searched in the path '/src/PrestaShopBundle/Controller/Admin/Sell/Order' but didn't find anything that could be useful

Is anyone able to help me?